# Excel VBA Global Variables

Tags: arrays, vba, variables, global

I can't find any documentation to support my findings but that is why I am here. In my modules I declare multiple global arrays this itself isn't an issue but what seems to be happening is that if I attempt to declare multiple arrays in one statement only the first is initialized. Can anyone confirm this to be the behaviour and/or point me towards documentation that supports this?

Example of not working statement

```
Global arr1, arr2, arr3
```

When I go into the code if I look for the definition of arr1 it can be found. If I look for either arr2 or arr3 I get a message that "Identifier under cusor is not recognized." If I move arr3 to a new line and decalre it as such:

```
Global arr1, arr2
Global arr3
```

It is now recognized. So I don't know if this is known behaviour, a bug, or other.

Comment: `Global a,b,c` is fine, all 3 should be defined without problems, you will need to expand your example. You can add `option explicit` to the top of the module; this will cause VBA to raise an error should you attempt to use an undeclared/out of scope variable. (Its also better to define a type `global a() as string, b() as string ...`)

Comment: In both cases all variables ``arr1``, ``arr2`` and ``arr3`` if declared that way you specified should work. And all those would be type of ``variant``. If you donot declare any type explicitly all variables become ``TypeOf`` ``variant`` default.

Comment: I can also declare variables as above and see their definitions in following code in the same and other modules.  I second the recommendation by @AlexK. to use Option Explicit.  One thing about Global variables is that they can't be declared inside a class - it won't compile (but that's clearly not your issue).

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
Global arr1, arr2, arr3

Sub test()

    Debug.Print CLng(arr1)
    Debug.Print CLng(arr2)
    Debug.Print CLng(arr3)

End Sub
```

As it prints three zeros.  You say "if I look for the definition of" but I'm not sure what that means.  If I put break point in the code and hover over the variables, they all return "Empty".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the use of "Global" instead of "Public".  I don't think the former is actually documented.
But anyway, arrX are all of type variant. they are not arrays specifically, until coerced.
As mentioned in a previous comment, arrays can be declared like this:
Dim arr1() as myType
Dim arr2(1 to 10) as myType

somewhere in the code you also need to initialise the structure of arr1
Redim arr1(i to j)

That's much safer and more efficient than muddling around with variants.
Variants can be efficient for reading and writing blocks of data but its best to convert them to arrays if you are going to work with them much.

Here are a couple of references, apart from MSDN:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/topic.aspx

http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-1/